# Custom search function for dictionary lookup

Tags: regular-expressions, functions, keyboard-macros

I have a plain text dictionary in which each headword is matched by

```
^# \(† \)?headword,
```

How can I make a custom search function that relieves me of typing 
the whole regex every time I want to look up a word?   I tried recording a keyboard macro, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do. I wasn't sure how you store the dictionary though.

```
(defun my-search (word)
  (interactive "sWord: ")
  ;; some code to open your dictionary file
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (re-search-forward (format "^# \\(† \\)?%s," word) nil t))
```

Comment: Thanks. The dictionary is in one file, I didn't think about looking up from another buffer.  Anyway, this doesn't seem to work ..

Comment: What does it do? more importantly, what do you expect it to do? All that code should do is prompt for a word, open a file (that code is missing), and search forward to the match.

Comment: It doesn't find what I search for.  For example, I have a line beginning with `# pugilist`, but that isn't found with the function.  I get prompted for a search word, but after I have entered `pugilist` nothing happens.  (Correction: point is moved to top of file.)

Comment: That probably means the regexp is wrong. What is the cross symbol in the parens? If you delete \(† \)? Does it work?

Comment: Should that matter with the question mark there?  I've tested it manually and it works.  (The dagger I think is put in front of obsolete words.)

Comment: I forgot to escape the \ in the regexp. Try the new version.

Comment: This looks correct AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

[Tags](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags-Tables.html) can do what you're asking with a different interface, which may or may not be more convenient than a custom function.

First, you need to build the the dictionary index file (the tags table), using the companion program [`etags`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Create-Tags-Table.html) that comes with Emacs. I assume the dictionary file is called `dict.txt`. This creates a file called `TAGS` in the current directory.

```
etags -lnone -r'/^#[ †]*\(\<[^,]+\),/\1/' dict.txt
```

Emacs will automatically look for the `TAGS` file in the current directory. If you want to read it from a different directory, call `visit-tags-table`. See [“selecting a tags table”](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Tags-Table.html) in the manual for more possibilities.

To look up a word that's already present in the buffer, move the cursor onto that word and press `M-.` (`xref-find-definitions` — was `find-tag` up to Emacs 24.x). To look up a different word, press `M-1 M-.` (or any other prefix argument with `M-.` and you'll be prompted for a word. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Looking-Up-Identifiers.html#Looking-Up-Identifiers-1) for other related commands. Also of interest is `complete-tag` (not bound to a key) which tries to complete the word under the cursor (completion is also available from the `M-.` prompt).